# MSMQ: Is it possible to consume the message in the same order as they were being sent?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

Let say I have a queue Q ,Q is the destination of message.
I know that MSMQ guarantees that **multi** messages encompassed in the transaction are received in the same order in which
they were sent.But my application send **one message per transaction** to Q(**messages have same destination**).Can messages order still being preserved when it reach Q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be OK although it may depend on how flaky the network is. MSMQ uses internal ack messages to ensure messages are successfully delivered. The retry mechanism will handle any lost messages. It may be possible, depending on retry window size, etc., for a lost message to be delayed behind the following message.

I can also imagine it may be possible for one message to get ahead of another - for example, a 1kb message following a 4MB message - due to the time it takes for a message to be persisted from the network stack to the disk.

Both scenarios are edge cases, though.

Bottom line is that order is not guaranteed outside a transaction so, if your app depends on it, make sure the messages contain a sequence number of some kind.

Comment: you mean that if the network is reliable,then "one message per transaction" can be received in the order??when the network is unreliable,the order can`t be guaranteed  if retry failed?

Comment: Normally the outgoing queue will act like a pipeline and messages will be delivered in sequence. Your application will be able to read them in the order they arrived in the queue. But you need to decide what the impact and risk of a message being processed out of sequence is. If it would lose you a million dollars then you may want to implement your own guaranteed ordering system. For example, using acknowledgements - application waits for the delivery acknowledgement of message M to return to the sender before sending message M+1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `servicebehaviour` is decoraated with  `EnsureOrderedDispatch:=true`

Here is the link that Microsoft is confirmed with

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/ordered-processing-of-messages-in-single-concurrency-mode

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802385/how-to-enforce-message-queue-sequence-with-multiple-wcf-service-instances).  It does refer to multiple clients, but the content of the post might be useful to you.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate then you mark it as so. If you want to answer then you should put the detail in your answer and link to the other question only to support what you've already written. Otherwise this is just a comment and should have been put in the comments under the question.

Comment: Didn't have enough rep to comment at that point! :(.  I don't think it's a direct duplicate, just similar.