# MSMQ: Does MSMQ guarantees sequential message passing?

Tags: c#, msmq, msmq-wcf

After load testing, I found some packets are not sequential.

it's a basic WCF service and client is continuously sending the request.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/napegadie_kones_msft_blog/2015/02/07/wcf-processes-messages-from-msmq-out-of-order-using-netmsmqbinding/) is what you are looking for. But I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802385/how-to-enforce-message-queue-sequence-with-multiple-wcf-service-instances) would be a more sustainable solution.

Comment: Does it mean, it doesn't assure sequential message passing.

Comment: Depending on the configuration an item could be placed in the retry queue. Your message order will then be changed by default. Don't design your solution depending on the message order.

Comment: MSMQ only guarantees message sequence within the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have guaranteed (in-order, exactly-once) delivery using netMsmqBinding.

The first thing you need to do is to create your actual MSMQ message queue transactional.

Secondly, you must tell WCF to enlist in the transaction like so:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
public void Handle(Something msg)
{
    ....
}
```

Lastly, you need to specify guaranteed behavior of the service by using the exactlyOnce binding paramter:

```
<netMsmqBinding>
  <binding name="netMsmqBinding_IMyServiceInterface" 
           exactlyOnce="true"> 
    ...
  </binding>
</netMsmqBinding>
```

ExactlyOnce tells WCF that we require transactions, that each message will be delivered exactly once and in the order they were sent.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did exactly same but it didn't guarantee sequence.

Comment: @User - were you able to have messages arriving in the wrong order? How did you achieve this? Also can you post your service interface and implementation pls?

Comment: @User also do you have a single service running or scale out more than one?

Comment: Redfem, I'll post code, yup. I sent datetime as parameter of method and checked it' sequence. And single service.